# Android Scrollview with TableLayout and Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have three layouts(2 relative layout and a table layout) in my XML with the scrollview. 
It's like

```
<RelativeLayout>
         <ScrollView>
              <RelativeLayout>
                    <TableLayout>
                    </TableLayout>
              </RelativeLayout>
          </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem i am facing is that i want the calendar Button (highlighted in the diagram) to be placed inside the scrollview's relativelayout but not in the tablelayout.

When i do this it aligns to parent bottom of TableLayout.

But i want the Calendar Button to be on the right of the Manufacturing date.(As highlighted in the diagram).

How can i do this. Can anyone Please Help me. I would be Thankful to u for your help.

[image]

Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/universalbg"
android:padding="20dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selected_tab" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/camera_icon" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="650dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Make"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/biggest_spinner" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Model"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/biggest_spinner" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Version"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/biggest_spinner" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Fuel Type"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/biggest_spinner" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Kilometers Driven"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Expected Price"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Negotiable"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Place of Registration"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/biggest_spinner" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Color"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text|textCapWords" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Manufacturing Date"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="DD/MM/YY"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textSize="22sp" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Description of Car"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="100"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Current Location of Car"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/biggest_spinner" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="No. of Owners"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/biggest_spinner" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Features"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/big_button_click"
                android:text="Add More Features"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner6"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_click"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

     <!-- Button For Calendar To be placed properly -->

    <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/calendar_icon" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add the button in the table row for manufacturing date. Adjust weights accordingly. You can actually remove all the heavy nesting and just do it with **ScrollView -> TableLayout**. None of the RelativeLayouts are really required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 <!-- Button For Calendar To be placed properly -->

<Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/editText5"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_icon" />
```